# Adding an additional Download PDF to orders

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, pdf, elementaction, download

Is there a hook or something I can use to add an additional Download PDF option to the Edit Order screen? It looks like a dropdown, but I can't find any docs on how to add to it.

[image: Download PDF dropdown]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Commerce 3.1.12 only the one PDF can be registered in general settings. We will be adding support for additional PDFs to be configured in the next release. Stay tuned.

Comment: Awesome - good to know thank you.